# Couldnt display data from firebase in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am developing an android app which shows the user with the latest jobs from various fields. I want to display the jobs that the user has applied so far in "Your Applications" section.

But the values are not getting retrieved. It displays a blank activity. I have attached the code.

### Applications.java

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Application;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Applications extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FirebaseUser user;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ArrayList<Post> posts;
    MyAdap adap;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    long maxid=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_applications);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.work);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        posts = new ArrayList<>();
        pd= new ProgressDialog(Applications.this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.show();

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Applications");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Job Applications");

        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild(String.valueOf(maxid+1)).equalTo(user.getUid());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Post p = ds.getValue(Post.class);
                    posts.add(p);
                }
                pd.dismiss();
                adap = new MyAdap(Applications.this, posts);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### Posts.java

```
    public class Post {
    private String jobtitle, jobtype, company, location;

    public Post() {
    }

    public Post(String jobtitle, String jobtype, String company, String location) {
        this.jobtitle = jobtitle;
        this.jobtype = jobtype;
        this.company = company;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getJobtitle() {
        return jobtitle;
    }

    public void setJobtitle(String jobtitle) {
        this.jobtitle = jobtitle;
    }

    public String getJobtype() {
        return jobtype;
    }

    public void setJobtype(String jobtype) {
        this.jobtype = jobtype;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
```

### MyAdap.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdap extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdap.ViewHolder> {

    Context cb;
    ArrayList<Post> posts;

    public MyAdap(Context c, ArrayList<Post> applications){
        cb=c;
        posts=applications;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(cb).inflate(R.layout.post, parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.jobTitle.setText(posts.get(position).getJobtitle());
        holder.jobType.setText(posts.get(position).getJobtype());
        holder.location.setText(posts.get(position).getLocation());
        holder.companyName.setText(posts.get(position).getCompany());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView jobTitle, jobType,companyName,location;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            jobTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jobTitle);
            jobType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.jobType);
            companyName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.companyName);
            location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.location);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the image of the database.

[image: Firebase]

Comment: Do you get any errors? Where is the layout xml? And your adapter?

Comment: Are you able to see "No adapter attached" in your logs ?

Comment: Plus, I find little strange your db and your query. Aren't you supposed to get a post?

Comment: I find no errors in the log and i have added the code for adapter.

Comment: Where do you set adapter? Maybe you set it outside of query (that is async), so it basicaly loads nothing.

Comment: public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Post p = ds.getValue(Post.class);
                    posts.add(p);
                }
                pd.dismiss();
                adap = new MyAdap(Applications.this, posts);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adap);
            }

Comment: Have you logged that query returns actually your desired post?

Comment: i didnt understand what you mean. can you please explain?

Comment: add Log.d(TAG, "count=" + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());  -- You can see in the Logcat output

Comment: now when i run the app, in logcat it shows E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Logcat -> debug -> search your TAG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not attaching adapter to recycle view

```
adap = new MyAdap(Applications.this, posts);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adap)
```

you need to set adpater to recycle view

Comment: can you check the list size ?

Comment: its working. the problem was i didnt set the adapter correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a problem with your `orderByChild` and `equalTo` method in the Query section. Please try without the Query and if you want to add sorting read details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sort_data). 
And one more thing you don't have any `jobtype` in your database but in your POJO class you have this field in your Constructor.

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Post p = ds.getValue(Post.class);
                posts.add(p);
            }
            pd.dismiss();
            adap = new MyAdap(Applications.this, posts);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Comment: but i want to show only the items which have the corresponding user id. i dont want to show all the items.

Comment: Ok then try 
 Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(user.getUid());

Comment: Its working. i think the problem was i didnt set the adapter correctly.

Comment: Do you change your POJO class you don't have any jobtype in you database? and I suggested you first try without Query for identity where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

As said by abdul add the adapter to the recycler view and also add the android lifecycle method onStart(); method and in the add adapter.startlisteneing();